# How do I narrow down scope when running an ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that takes a lot of time to execute, partly due to having a lot of nodes on which it has to run on (I am wasting time with ansible checking the status of all the nodes), and I need to make some changes somewhere in the middle of it.

What would be the best way in which I could narrow down the scope of the playbook? I've considered isolating the required change and/or just running the modified part on a single node?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what [tags](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_tags.html) are for.

You can tag any tasks with any combination of tags and then specify that combination of tags to run (or, alternatively, to skip with `--skip-tags`) which will then only run those specified tasks.

So an example playbook may look like this:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: copy foo
      copy:
        src:  path/to/foo
        dest: path/to/foo
      tags:
        - copy_foo
        - copy
        - foo

    - name: copy bar
      copy:
        src:  path/to/bar
        dest: path/to/bar
      tags:
        - copy_bar
        - copy
        - bar

    - name: restart foo
      service:
        name:  foo
        state: restarted
      tags:
        - restart_foo
        - restart
        - foo

    - name: restart bar
      service:
        name:  bar
        state: restarted
      tags:
        - restart_bar
        - restart
        - bar
```

I can then run just the "restart foo" task with `ansible-playbook -i path/to/hosts playbook.yml --tags "restart_foo"`. Alternatively I could run all the bar related tags and also restart foo (but not copying foo) with any combination of the following:

- `ansible-playbook -i path/to/hosts playbook.yml --tags "bar,restart_foo"`
- `ansible-playbook -i path/to/hosts playbook.yml --tags "restart,copy_bar"`
- `ansible-playbook -i path/to/hosts playbook.yml --skip-tags "copy_foo"`

If you want to instead (or as a combination) limit the nodes that a play is ran against then you can do that with [`--limit`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#top-level-playbooks-are-separated-by-role) option. So if you want to limit the play to just web servers then you could run it with `ansible-playbook -i path/to/hosts playbook.yml --limit webservers` or even limit it to a single specific host with `ansible-playbook -i path/to/hosts playbook.yml --limit web.example.org`

Answer (score 8):

Sadly this is not really documented, even if is very useful

```
ansible-playbook -i "hostname," site.yml
```

You can list multiple hosts if you want. As you can see you need to put a comma after the name to make it realise it is a list.

Comment: this would limit the target hosts, but I don't think that's what OP asked for

Comment: @eis you are partially right. If you have groups inside your inventory this may not do what you expect because it does not filter them. Still, I was not able to find another workaround yet. One that would continue to use the same inventory.ini file but that will skip any other hosts, so it will run only activities that would have to apply to the one I want.