# running an Ansible playbook against a single host

Tags: ansible

I'm using a `hosts` file for static inventory:

```
server1 ansible_ssh_host=1.1.1.1
server2 ansible_ssh_host=1.1.1.2
server3 ansible_ssh_host=1.1.1.3

[group1]
server1
server2
```

And I've got a playbook `example.yml` like this:

```
---
- name: base setup
  become: true
  hosts:
    - group1
  roles:
    - base
```

I'd like to an `ansible-playbook` test run using `example.yml`, but *only* against the host **server1**. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 29):

Well I finished writing this question, then my SO search-fu improved. Here are some answers:

Using `-l SUBSET`:

[Running an Ansible Playbook on a particular group of servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129422/running-an-ansible-playbook-on-a-particular-group-of-servers)

Using `-i "hostname,"`:

[How do I narrow down scope when running an ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883525/how-do-i-narrow-down-scope-when-running-an-ansible-playbook)

Comment: The `-i` is not so helpful because your group `group1` will get lost. But `-l server1` or  `--limit server1` is the way to go, yes.

Comment: how to limit group play is run on in playbook source code itself?

Comment: that comma got me.

Comment: ```-l SUBSET``` also works like this ```-l "hostname_*"``` which will find all hosts that start with ```hostname_```